# Async function not supported in NodeJS app deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, async-await

I'm trying to implement asynchronous functionality in one of my routes in a NodeJS app. It works when I run it on localhost but when deployed to heroku, an error `unexpected token (` is thrown in the first line of the following code:

```
router.post('/post', async(req,res) => {
    const data = await getData();
    //do stuff

})
```

I'm a little confused as to why this works in one environment and not the other. Are there heroku configurations I'm missing? Do I need to explicitly add support for ES2016/2017 in Heroku?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version (you'll need at least version 7)

Comment: Thanks - good call, if you care to add an answer I'll upvote it.@robertklep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku defaults to the latest Long Term Support version of Node (which, as of writing, is v6.11.1) if you don't set a specific version.

`async/await` has been available in Node since v7.6, so you'll need to explicitly specify at least that version in your `package.json`, as documented here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this link

[Es6_hrku](http://masnun.com/2015/07/11/es6-on-node-js-and-heroku.html)

You need to convert your ES6 to ES5 in order to make it happen on heroku. 
Changes required in package.json.